# chanA <- chanB : send and receive value or send channel itself?

Tags: go, channel

It seems like the Go compiler will do two completely different semantic operations depending on the types in the following example:

chanA <- chanB

If chanA is type (chan chan<- string), this operation will send chanB, type (chan<- string), itself to chanA.

However, if chanA is type (chan<- string), it will try to extract a string from chanB, implying chanB's type is (<-chan string).

Is the only way to reason about this to know the types, or is there an easy way to tell when a channel is sending values vs. itself?

I am looking at this example from the Go Programming Book: https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/chat/chat.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to tell.

```
chanA <- anything
```

is sending the value `anything` on `chanA`, no matter what `anything` is.

```
chanA <- <- chanB
```

is receiving a value from `chanB` and sending it on `chanA`.

Your second statement here:

> However, if chanA is type (chan<- string), it will try to extract a string from chanB

is your issue. `foo <- bar` is *always* a send operation. The Go compiler reads from left to right, and `identifier <-` is a send operation.

A receive operation is an expression that evaluates to a value, so it can only be valid where a value would be valid - i.e., the compiler must have already encountered the first part of an assignment operation, send operation, function call, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong.

```
chanA <- chanB
```

The above will only work if `chanA` is of type `chan chan something`. It will send `chanB` over `chanA`. It will not read from `chanB`.

To read a value from `chanB` and send it over `chanA`, you need:

```
chanA <- <- chanB
```